# Server with VPN and public IP

Tags: ubuntu, vpn

I have an Ubuntu Server connected to an VPN (as client, not as server). I need to allow external connections to my server using the server's public IP, but when I activate the VPN, I can only connect throught it.

Any solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your VPN server might be forcing all traffic through it.  See if you have the option for split-tunnel so only specific traffic routes over the VPN.

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot see the VPN server configuration, but if it could be a server bad configuration... I will contact with my VPN provider. Thanks!

Comment: Finally, my solution was create a manual splitting into the client using this guide https://gist.github.com/jagtesh/5531300

Answer (score 0):

You should remove

```
default-gateway
```

option from your client OpenVPN configuration file, so it won't redirect all traffic through VPN. If there is no such option there, than this probably is pulled from the OpenVPN server itself. In that case you need to add:

```
route-nopull
```

option to your client config and manually specify all routes to whichever IPs you want to be accessed through VPN by adding:

```
route 192.168.1.0/24
route www.example.com
route 1.2.3.4
route etc...
```

to your clients config file.

Comment: I'm using `vpnc` and in my `.conf` there isn't any `default-gateway` option.

Comment: And... If I add manually those options, I get this:

    vpnc: warning: unknown configuration directive in ./corp-vpn.conf at line 12
    vpnc: warning: unknown configuration directive in ./corp-vpn.conf at line 13

Comment: What is it at the line 13 exactly? You don't have to just copy them, you have to add *routes you need*...

Comment: The line I added following your advice. Don't worry, it's solved.